# 4clojure palindrome number timeout issue

Tags: clojure

I don't understand why the palindrome number puzzle on 4clojure [Problem 150](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/150) does timeout when I post my solution. On my local REPL everything is pretty fast. I found this [solution](https://gist.github.com/ummels/1647608) and it works but it has a similar performance as my solution. I know it's a lot of code but the problem ain't easy. Hope the comments help to get the idea.

```
(defn palindrome [n] 
  (let [ ;; given a number return a string
        digits (fn [^String x]  (String/valueOf x))              
    ;; given a string return the length
        digits-count  (fn [^String x] ( .length x) ) 
    ;; given an input sequence of digits, return a number. e.g. (seqstr (seq "1234")) => 1234
        seqstr  #(Long/parseLong (apply str %)) 
    ;; true when the given string has an even number of digits:
    even-digits? #(even? (digits-count %)) 
    ;; return the left middle of a string. For even-digit strings returns the 'real' left part, for odd-digit strings returns one digit more. 
    ;; e.g. (left-middle "12345678") => "1234"
    ;; e.g. (left-middle "1234567")  => "1234"
        left-middle #(if (even-digits? %) 
              (subs % 0 (quot (digits-count % ) 2) ) 
          (subs % 0 (inc (quot (digits-count % ) 2)))) 
    ;; mirror a given number. 
    ;; (mirror [1234 :even] ) => 12344321
    ;; (mirror [1234 :odd] )  => 1234321
        mirror (fn [[num dig]]
           (let [ d (seq (digits num))]
            (if (= :even dig) (seqstr (concat d (reverse d)))    
                        (seqstr (concat d (drop 1 (reverse d)))))))

    ;; initialize loop given a string. Returns a vector given a starting point.
    ;; (init "12345678") => [1234 :even 10000]
    ;; (init "1234567" ) => [1234 :odd  10000]
    ;; the first item in the vector contains the number we start the iteration with.
    ;; the flag indicates whether we should mirror it to an even or odd-digit number
    ;; the goal (power of 10) indicates when the next switch between odd/even-digit numbers will occur
    init #(let [s (left-middle %)] 
           (vector (Long/parseLong s) 
                (if (even-digits? %) :even :odd) 
            (long (Math/pow 10 (digits-count s)))))

    ;; given a vector (see structure above), determine the next step
      ;;(next  [999 :even 1000] ) => [1000 :odd 10000] . When finished mirroring even-digit numbers of length 3, continue with mirroring 4-digit odd-digit numbers
      ;;(next [9999 :odd 10000] ) => [1000 :even 10000]. When finished mirroring odd-digit numbers of length 4, continue with mirroring 4-digit even-digit numbers
    ;;(next [123 :odd 1000])    => [124 :odd 1000]. The normal case.
    next (fn [[num even goal]] 
         (let [m (inc num)] 
          (if (= m goal)
            (if (= even :even)
              [goal :odd (* 10 goal)]
              [(/ goal 10) :even goal])
            [m even goal] )))
   i  (init (digits n)) 
   palindromes (iterate next i) ] 
  (filter (partial <= n ) (map mirror palindromes))))
```

If you paste the code above in a REPL you will be able to evaluate the folloing unit tests:

```
(= (take 26 (palindrome 0))
   [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
    11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 
    101 111 121 131 141 151 161])

(= (take 16 (palindrome 162))
   [171 181 191 202 
    212 222 232 242 
    252 262 272 282 
    292 303 313 323])

(= (take 6 (palindrome 1234550000))
   [1234554321 1234664321 1234774321 
    1234884321 1234994321 1235005321])  

(= (first (palindrome (* 111111111 111111111)))
   (* 111111111 111111111))

(= (set (take 199 (palindrome 0)))
   (set (map #(first (palindrome %)) (range 0 10000))))

(= true 
  (apply < (take 6666 (palindrome 9999999))))

(= (nth (palindrome 0) 10101)
   9102019)
```

For the 'slowest' test (number 5) I get the following performance:

```
user=> (time (= (set (take 199 (palindrome 0)))
   (set (map #(first (palindrome %)) (range 0 10000)))))
  "Elapsed time: 66.509472 msecs"
```

I don't really understand what the 'timeout' criteria is on the 4clojure homepage. Everthing below 1 second should work in my opinion. I used Clojure 1.5.1 on JRE 7 as well as clojure 1.2.1 on JRE 6.

It's my forth attempt to solve this puzzle and most of my solutions struggle with test 5 but I don't clearly see the point in saying it's slow. Am I using too much ram? recursions? I am new to this language and any cool hint would be appreciated:

My first solution is a bit slower, but finishes in around 600ms on my machine.

```
(defn palindrome [n] 
  (let [
    digits         #(seq (str %))      ;; given a number return a seq of its digits
    digits-count   #(count (digits %)) ;; given a number return how many digits it has 
    seqstr         #(Long/parseLong (apply str %))  ;; seq to number
    start          (seqstr (take (/ (digits-count n) 2) (digits n)))
    digits-range   #(map long (range (max (Math/pow 10 (dec %)) start) (Math/pow 10 %)))  ;; return all numbers of given digits length
    mirror         #(let [d (digits %1)]
                       (if (true? %2) (seqstr (concat d (reverse d)))     ;; mirror 1234 true  => 12344321 even number of digits 
                                      (seqstr (concat d (drop 1 (reverse d)))))) ;; mirror 1234 false => 1234321  odd number of digits

    digits-seq     #(drop (/ (digits-count %) 2) (range)) ;; e.g. when input number has 10 digits, result is a seq: 5, 6, 7, 8, ....
                                                          ;;      when input number has  9 digits, result is a seq: 5, 6, 7, 8, ....
    input-even     (even? (digits-count n))                                                   
    ]
(filter #(<= n %) (cons 0 (mapcat #(concat (map (fn [x]  (mirror x false))  (if (and input-even (* 2 %)) [] (digits-range %))) 
                                  (map (fn [x]   (mirror x true ))  (digits-range %)) ) (digits-seq n) )))))
```

Comment: I think the "timeout" is a criteria that is set individually for each puzzle. The goal of 4clojure is pedagogical, and part of that is helping you learn what does and doesn't perform well. Turning numbers into strings and breaking that into characters and then numbers again is far from the most efficient way to carry out this task. There is shorter, more readable code that solves the puzzle in significantly less time.

Comment: I don't know, but it is also possible the authors might play dirty by mocking some functions, e.g. string conversions, to be much slower than in your REPL, again, for pedagogical purposes.

Comment: I am well aware of numbers to string (and back) conversions but on 4clojure it's always stated what you are not allowed to use. For this puzzle I can't see any restrictions.

Comment: @noisesmith: you're missing a proof for what your saying that it's not efficient. The solution I've linked to does not outperform mine in any order of magnitude. Sure there exists code from clojurians that will look much better and be much more understandable but unless I solve a puzzle I don't have access to it. The question I ask here on SO is to help me understand what could possibly go wrong when posted on 4clojure portal.

Comment: @a.webb: Actually in my early attempts I was using less string manipulations but I thought it might give better performance when I moved towards strings since they're pretty much optimized in the jvm. So the solution I posted was an attempt to get the fastest I could on the repl, but sure - when they penalize such functions, I could never complete the puzzle.

Comment: @noisesmith: I think you're very wrong. You need a decimal representation of the numbers to solve the problem, and strings are decent way to get that. What this problem tries to teach is rather that it's much more efficient to generate the palindromes than to iterate through all integers and check for palindromes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each 4clojure puzzle has one or more pedagogical purposes. You have the correct algorithm, but the timeout test is punishing you for using too many conversions from and to strings.

The culprit is your mirror function, which converts a number to a string, manipulates it, and then converts it back to a number.

Try plugging in this alternative, which does not require string conversion and manipulation:

```
    mirror (fn [[num dig]]
             (loop [a num, r (if (= dig :even) num (quot num 10))]
               (if (= 0 r)
                 a
                 (recur (+ (* a 10) (mod r 10)), (quot r 10)))))
```

Here's a full passing solution based on your original post, with just a few other minor changes:

```
(fn palindrome [n] 
  (let [even-digits? #(even? (count %)) 
        left-middle #(if (even-digits? %) 
                       (subs % 0 (quot (count % ) 2) ) 
                       (subs % 0 (inc (quot (count % ) 2)))) 
        mirror (fn [[num dig]]
                 (loop [a num r (if (= dig :even) num (quot num 10))]
                   (if (= 0 r)
                     a
                     (recur (+ (* a 10) (mod r 10)) (quot r 10)))))
        init #(let [s (left-middle %)] 
                (vector (Long/parseLong s) 
                        (if (even-digits? %) :even :odd) 
                        (long (Math/pow 10 (count s)))))
        nextp (fn [[num even goal]] 
               (let [m (inc num)] 
                 (if (= m goal)
                   (if (= even :even)
                     [goal :odd (* 10 goal)]
                     [(/ goal 10) :even goal])
                   [m even goal] )))
        i  (init (str n)) 
        palindromes (iterate nextp i) ] 
    (filter (partial <= n ) (map mirror palindromes))))
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. It still times out though using your mirror function, I might need to swap out more string manipulations.but I guess your comment with the mock might be the reason for it. I am aware that putting ints to a string gives me easy access to the digits but I didn't think that this cheating was their pedagogical purpose. For me the pedagogical key was to iterate from the middle digits and than mirror the number. Sure I can do it also with vectors. I'll give it a try this evening. Thanx.

Comment: Right, one of the other minor changes I made must have made the difference. Posted full code that passes. You can see my inferior but passing answer under awebb.

Comment: I couldn't resist to try a solution myself without using strings. worked immmediatly. Here the code if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6890101.

Comment: @shaft Cool. A solution that uses only strings (except at the very beginning for the input and end for the output) should also be passable.